# producteev4j implementation

Tags: java, android, authentication, crash, implementation

hey guys here at stackoverflow.com I'm a student and developing a small todo app for myself with producteev integration. Now I found a Library called Producteev4j that can be found at: http://code.google.com/p/producteev4j/

I downloaded and added the jar to my project. 
but because of the spare doc I can't relly figure out how to implement it. I made a button with the following excerpt of code:

```
ProducteevTransport transport = new com.producteev4j.transport.SimpleTransportImpl();
                ((SimpleTransportImpl) transport).setApiKey("myapi");
                ((SimpleTransportImpl) transport).setApiSecret("mysecret");
                 if(service==null){
                        service = ProducteevServiceFactory.getService("com.producteev4j.services.version0.ProducteevServiceV0",transport);
                        }

try {
                    userLogin = service.userLogin(EMAIL, PASSWORD);
                } catch (ProducteevSignatureException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ProducteevServiceException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ProducteevException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                 userToken = userLogin.getToken();
```

and these variables:

```
private ProducteevService service=null;
private UserLogin userLogin;
```

But that doesn't work, always I click the button the Application crashes with the following (this is the complete log file of one run)

```
01-03 12:33:37.585: D/dalvikvm(244): GC freed 832 objects / 62864 bytes in 82ms
01-03 12:33:37.895: D/dalvikvm(244): GC freed 51 objects / 1936 bytes in 53ms
01-03 12:33:38.195: D/dalvikvm(244): GC freed 132 objects / 6240 bytes in 55ms
01-03 12:33:38.475: D/dalvikvm(244): GC freed 58 objects / 2312 bytes in 54ms
01-03 12:33:38.765: D/dalvikvm(244): GC freed 62 objects / 6112 bytes in 54ms
01-03 12:33:39.175: D/ViewFlipper(244): updateRunning() mVisible=true, mStarted=false, mUserPresent=true, mRunning=false
01-03 12:33:47.925: E/dalvikvm(244): Could not find class 'org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper', referenced from method com.producteev4j.marshall.JacksonMappingUtil.<clinit>
01-03 12:33:47.925: W/dalvikvm(244): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 146 (Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper;) in Lcom/producteev4j/marshall/JacksonMappingUtil;
01-03 12:33:47.925: D/dalvikvm(244): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
01-03 12:33:47.925: D/dalvikvm(244): Making a copy of Lcom/producteev4j/marshall/JacksonMappingUtil;.<clinit> code (32 bytes)
01-03 12:33:47.935: W/dalvikvm(244): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/codehaus/jackson/type/JavaType;)
01-03 12:33:47.935: I/dalvikvm(244): Could not find method org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.canDeserialize, referenced from method com.producteev4j.marshall.JacksonMappingUtil.canRead
01-03 12:33:47.935: W/dalvikvm(244): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 786: Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper;.canDeserialize (Lorg/codehaus/jackson/type/JavaType;)Z
01-03 12:33:47.935: D/dalvikvm(244): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
01-03 12:33:47.935: D/dalvikvm(244): Making a copy of Lcom/producteev4j/marshall/JacksonMappingUtil;.canRead code (40 bytes)
01-03 12:33:47.935: I/dalvikvm(244): Could not find method org.codehaus.jackson.map.type.TypeFactory.type, referenced from method com.producteev4j.marshall.JacksonMappingUtil.getJavaType
01-03 12:33:47.935: W/dalvikvm(244): VFY: unable to resolve static method 788: Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/type/TypeFactory;.type (Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;)Lorg/codehaus/jackson/type/JavaType;
01-03 12:33:47.935: D/dalvikvm(244): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0000
01-03 12:33:47.935: D/dalvikvm(244): Making a copy of Lcom/producteev4j/marshall/JacksonMappingUtil;.getJavaType code (28 bytes)
01-03 12:33:47.945: W/dalvikvm(244): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/codehaus/jackson/type/JavaType;)
01-03 12:33:47.945: I/dalvikvm(244): Could not find method org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue, referenced from method com.producteev4j.marshall.JacksonMappingUtil.read
01-03 12:33:47.945: W/dalvikvm(244): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 787: Lorg/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper;.readValue (Ljava/io/InputStream;Lorg/codehaus/jackson/type/JavaType;)Ljava/lang/Object;
01-03 12:33:47.945: D/dalvikvm(244): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000c
01-03 12:33:47.945: D/dalvikvm(244): Making a copy of Lcom/producteev4j/marshall/JacksonMappingUtil;.read code (282 bytes)
01-03 12:33:47.945: W/dalvikvm(244): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 140 (Lorg/codehaus/jackson/JsonParseException;)
01-03 12:33:47.945: W/dalvikvm(244): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x2e
01-03 12:33:47.955: W/dalvikvm(244): VFY:  rejected Lcom/producteev4j/marshall/JacksonMappingUtil;.read (Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
01-03 12:33:47.955: W/dalvikvm(244): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x002e
01-03 12:33:47.955: W/dalvikvm(244): VFY:  rejected Lcom/producteev4j/marshall/JacksonMappingUtil;.read (Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
01-03 12:33:47.955: W/dalvikvm(244): Verifier rejected class Lcom/producteev4j/marshall/JacksonMappingUtil;
01-03 12:33:47.955: D/AndroidRuntime(244): Shutting down VM
01-03 12:33:47.955: W/dalvikvm(244): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
01-03 12:33:47.955: E/AndroidRuntime(244): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244): java.lang.VerifyError: com.producteev4j.marshall.JacksonMappingUtil
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at com.producteev4j.transport.SimpleTransportImpl._doGet(SimpleTransportImpl.java:29)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at com.producteev4j.transport.AbstractTransport.process(AbstractTransport.java:69)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at com.producteev4j.transport.AbstractTransport.process(AbstractTransport.java:52)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at com.producteev4j.services.version0.ProducteevUserServiceV0Impl.userLogin(ProducteevUserServiceV0Impl.java:123)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at com.producteev4j.services.version0.ProducteevServiceV0.userLogin(ProducteevServiceV0.java:85)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at producteev.push.Producteev_pushActivity$2.onClick(Producteev_pushActivity.java:87)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6541)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:884)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1659)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1107)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2061)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1691)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
01-03 12:33:47.975: E/AndroidRuntime(244):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 12:33:47.985: I/dalvikvm(244): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
01-03 12:33:48.006: I/dalvikvm(244): Wrote stack trace to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

would be great if somebody could have a look at.
yours flo

Comment: I essentially have the same error but I have the 1.9.5 jar version already (and I tried the 1.9.3 and that doesn't work either). Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
01-03 12:33:47.945: W/dalvikvm(244): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Lorg/codehaus/jackson/type/JavaType;)
01-03 12:33:47.945: I/dalvikvm(244): Could not find method org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue, referenced from method com.producteev4j.marshall.JacksonMappingUtil.read
```

you need to add http://jackson.codehaus.org/ library

download this one with mapper http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.3/jackson-all-1.9.3.jar

Comment: I was experiencing OP's problem while using Jackson 2.0.4. I swapped it for the single library from 1.9.*, and it was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry about the lack of documentation ( I didn´t have much spare time to do it ).

As already mentioned, you were missing the two dependencies that the project have, which are the jackson libraries.

I have updated the documentation a bit more.

If you have any problems do not hesitate to contact me thought the Issues at the project page.

The use of the library is simple, you have an interface "ProducteevService" (in the wiki I tell you how to configure it, with or without spring), and thought that , you have (almost all) the services provided by the producteev api. It returns some class, which is the response with the response data.

Regards

Juan